# Skip login form when back button is pressed

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a situation where I link to a "protected" page (`xxx.php`) which determines that the user needs to login before continuing onward. So `xxx.php` displays a login page. Upon successful login it continues to the next page in the applications, etc., etc., etc. with no problems. The problem is that when the user presses their browser back button on the top page of the application (first page after the login) they are returned to the login form rather than the page that linked to the login form.

Basically:

`index.html -> xxx.php`

if logged in, continue to #app page (second page of `xxx.php`)
    else display login form and process user response, on success continue on to #app page

I'm sure the answer is somewhere in the hash/cache logic of jquery mobile, just not sure where because I am new to it and don't have a real good understanding of it yet.

Notes:

I use `$.mobile.changePage('#app')` to invoke the application after a successful login.

I use a normal `<a href="xxx.php">` link to get to `xxx.php` from `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

I know it sounds strange, but if you treat the login as a dialog, then the Back functionality will skip it, but I've never tried this with different .html/.php pages, only with divs within the same template

You could also over-ride the Back functionality on that page to be a direct link to index.html by using:

```
$("#myBackButton").live("click",function(){
    window.location = "index.html";
    return false;
});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Note `.live()` has been deprecated for [`.on()` in jQuery 1.7 =>](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Seem the best result was set changeHash to false when doing the changepage to main page after authentication.